# counting occurrences in an SSRS table

Tags: reporting-services

Working on SSRS. Have the following data set.

```
ID       City      Country
1       London     England
2       Glasgow    Scotland
3       Aberdeen   Scotland
4       Swansea    Wales
5       London     England
6       Glasgow    Scotland
7       Glasgow    Scotland
8       Manchester England
```

Would like to have a table, grouped by the city and showing how many occurrences there have been for each city, see below?

```
   City         Country      Total
  Glasgow       Scotland       3
  London        England        2
  Manchester    England        1
  Swansea       Wales          1
  Aberdeen      Scotland       1
```

How would i go about doing this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a group of `City` use the following expression:

```
=COUNT(Fields!City.Value,"City")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks alejandro, great help

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your question that you don't want the detail in the report, only the summary data.  If you do want detail, Alejandro Zuleta's answer will work.  If you don't need the detail, you can do the grouping in your dataset:

```
select city, country, count(*) as total
  from <yourtable>
 group by city, country;
```